# accidentally removed log folder in rails .gitignore, log folder not being generated on pull request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I'm new to git and rails. I checked out a rails project and had a bunch of log files come in with it. I wanted to remove the log files and add an entry into .gitignore to ignore contents of the log directory. I think I screwed up because when my colleague tried to checkout from master, his log directory didn't even get generated. I think instead of ignoring contents of the log file, I ignored the entire log directory. What's the best way to change this .gitignore file to only ignore log files NOT the log directory itself? Also I don't think I need all these things in the .gitignore. What's a nice clean and simple .gitignore for a rails project?

```
*.sublime-*
.bundle
db/*.sqlite3*
log/*.log
*.log
tmp/**/*
tmp/*
Gemfile.lock
doc/api
doc/app
*.swp
*~
.DS_Store
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git ignores empty folders, in fact it doesn't really know they exist (it knows about trees pointing toward file contents). Since there is no file content to point to, there is no tree and hence git will not create a folder.

Common way around this is to add empty file within the folder. Convention is to name this file `.keep`. Add such file to the empty folder, add it to the index, commit and push and folder will be created on checkout.

Comment: Thank you! So there is no real issue with the way I have the above .gitignore file which caused the log file to be deleted?

Comment: You can also use a .gitignore file instead of a .keep, because the .keep may be picked up by build tools whereas .gitignore is one of the 'well known' files to be ignored.

Comment: I don't understand. Is my gitignore above removing the log file? How do I fix this? Also the tmp dir got killed I'm going to have to keep one file in tmp as well. Should I edit .gitignore or use .keep? Please help with the file i have above.

Comment: The point is that git will not track empty folders. As long as there is sth, git will create the folder. The comment above is only telling to name this extra file .gitignore rather than .keep. (I prefer to use .keep as it easy to know when it is not needed anymore. .gitignore suggests it is important file )